# Shift Register PISO

Tags: vhdl, shift-register

Which is the meaning of clear and clock input for a parallel input/serial output shift register?. I was analyzing that code:

```
Entity shiftop is
port(clk,c :in bit;x :in bit_vector(7 downto 0);tx:out bit );
end entity;

architecture shift_arch of shiftop is
signal shift :bit_vector(7 downto 0):="00000000";

begin
shift<=x when (c='1' and c'event) else  
       '0'& shift (7 downto 1) when(clk='1' and clk'event) else
        shift;
tx<=shift(0); 
end architecture;
```

What I don't understand, is the meaning of that "c" that, I suppose, is something like CLEAR input or something to load the input x in the register.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Please describe what your problem is, include any code samples.

Comment: I hope you realize that without that code nobody could ever have answered your question....The 'c' seem an rising edge load signal. In my opinion that code should be discarded as very badly written and I don't think it can be synthesized.

Comment: Yes. I did not show the code just beacause I thought the question was "basic". I mean, all shift register have a clock input and a clear input too (perhaps!). Really sorry for that. That code is something  that I "inherited" and I was trying to understand.

Comment: `when (c='1' and c'event)` and `when(clk='1' and clk'event)`: to edge-triggered statements in one assignment? That will not synthesize... The code "needs a lot of work" :/

Comment: If you were to examine 6.1.3.5 Edge-sensitive storage using concurrent signal assignment statements in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn) you'd find it is required to adhere to the requirements of 6.1.3.1 Edge-sensitive storage from a process with sensitivity list and one clock (a conditional concurrent assignment statement  is elaborated into an equivalent process). Historically your construct isn't included as synthesis eligible when containing two clocks (c and clk). The condition for c as an asynchronous reset would be `when c = 1` (parentheses aren't necessary).

Comment: The code above, is something I need to understand just because is a component for a 8 bit serial adder. For me, was not clear the use of "two clock" (c and clk). The c input for the register, becomes high when, in the adder VHDL file (the "main file"), where the PISO shif reg. is used, happens something like: `if((clk='1' and clk'event)and(cont=0)) then c<='1'` and so the input value is loaded in the shift register. @Oldfart @JHBonarius @user11555120

Comment: It is a shift register with one clock for the parallel load (`c`) and another for the shift (`clk`). Perfectly usable for simulation but you may encounter difficulties if you want to synthesize it Check first that your hardware target (ASIC standard cells library or FPGA) supports D-flip-flops with 2 clocks.

Comment: @michele_ub From your last comment we can deduce that your design uses logic signals (`c`) as clocks. It is doable but you would need to take care of proper amplification of this signal with a clock tree and, more difficult, consider the skew between this clock and the main one. There is a non negligible probability that this has been designed by somebody who does not know much about digital hardware design.

Comment: I realize, from your first comment, that `c` is not a clock, but stands for parallel load. Just to be precise, I don't need to synthesize that code, but just simulate and see the results using gtkwave. Thanks @RenaudPacalet.